# How to use token to make certain lines readOnly in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I want to try and use tokens and make certain lines of code readOnly. 
For example;

```
class DeclareVarInit {
// declare constants 
// DEDUCTION to be 2000 and 
// TAX_RATE to be 0.2
//




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // variables
    double incomeTax, taxableIncome, grossSalary;

    //declare numOfChildren and initialize to 2 
    //declare numOfParents and initialize to 2 


    int numOfDependents;

    // assignment statements
    grossSalary = 100000;
    numOfDependents = numOfChildren + numOfParents;
    taxableIncome = grossSalary - numOfDependents*DEDUCTION;
    incomeTax = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE;
    System.out.println("The income tax is " + incomeTax);
} }
```

I want to make the commented lines // to be editable and rest of them readOnly. 
I'm a total noob at this so I need some help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `markText` method's `readOnly` option to make the specific lines of code read only.
You can find more details here https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText

Update:

Example : Following code will mark the line 1 & 2 as read only.

`var marker = editor.markText({line: 0, ch: 0}, {line: 1}, {readOnly: false});`

And if you want to dynamically makes changes, remove the previous marker using 
`marker.clear();`

and then add another marker for the new text.

Comment: That is good to use and all, but it doesn't work dynamically. Because I'm trying to create exercises for people to learn how to do programming so there's different exercises. And each exercises differ from each other so i can't just set a specific line to be readOnly.

Comment: Yes, It's possible to use it in your scenario.
I've updated an example hope that will help.